# How to transfer all items of a multiple select into another multiple select?

Tags: jquery

I can transfer selected items from a multiple select element into another one :

```
<script language="javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
     $('#btnOne').click(function() {
      return !$('#users_interdits option:selected').remove().appendTo('#users_autorises');
     });
     $('#btnUndoOne').click(function() {
      return !$('#users_autorises option:selected').remove().appendTo('#users_interdits');
     });
    });
</script>
```

This code doesn't take into account the "send all" functionnality in which case when I click a "send all" button then all remaining items within #users_interdits are transfered into #users_autorises.
How to do that ?

Comment: Post the code for "Send All" handler...

Comment: `appendTo` will automatically move the elements from one place in the DOM to another, there is no reason to do a .remove() before your appendTo call.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have _you_ written the code you have? It is trivial to implement what you need using the code you already have as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to remove the `:selected` selector to match all options:

```
$("#users_interdits option").appendTo("#users_autorises");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnOne, #sendAll').on('click', function() {
    $('#users_interdits option'+($(this).is('#btnOne') ? ':selected' : ''))
        .remove()
        .appendTo('#users_autorises');
});
```

The only difference is that, to send ALL options across, you don't nee the `:selected` pseudo-selector.

I am assuming you mean you actually want to empty options from one select and move them to another, rather than having options live in both selects. If the latter, just get rid of the call to `remove()`.

Comment: See Ohgodwhy's comment above: `appendTo()` will remove the elements before appending them to their new parent, so calling `remove()` is not necessary here. You would have to `clone()` the elements if you wanted them to exist in both parents.

Comment: Ah, interesting - I thought `append()` cloned rather than removed. +1.